# Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension before Creating VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

When running the below Azure Powershell, I get error:

> Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension : Can not perform requested
>   operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'mycomputer' not found.

```
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -Id $image.Id
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -StorageAccountType $vmStorageType -DiskSizeInGB $vmDiskSize -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore "My" -CertificateUrl $certURL
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -VMName $vmName -Name $extenstionName -Location $location -StorageAccountName $storageName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey -FileName $fileName -ContainerName $containerName -Run $fileName
$vm = New-AzureRmVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -Location $location
```

Can I not set the CustomScriptExtension as part of building the New VM?

Answer (score 0):

The `Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension` command can be used to add the Custom Script extension to an existing virtual machine. Existing VM. so no, you cannot do that before creating a VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript#powershell-deployment

Comment: I cannot find any other command that allows you to do it as part of a new VM, do you know if such command exists?

Answer (score 0):

VM custom script extension is a separate task that need create VM firstly. So, just adjust the execution order of your script.

```
##create a VM, no need $vm
New-AzureRmVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -Location $location
##create custom script extension
Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -VMName $vmName -Name $extenstionName -Location $location -StorageAccountName $storageName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey -FileName $fileName -ContainerName
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.